# DescribeFunction Parameters With Variadic Template Types

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, variadic-templates, variadic

I want to write a template function which takes in a function pointer and all but the last 2 arguments to that function. Something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename... ARGS>
void foo(void(*func)(ARGS..., T*, int*), ARGS... params);
```

I'd like to do something like the following:

1. Given a function of the signature `void bar(bool, char*, int*)`, I'd like to call: `foo(bar, false)`
2. Given a function of the signature `void bar(bool, int*, int*)`, I'd like to call: `foo(bar, false)`
3. Given a function of the signature `void bar(char*, int*)`, I'd like to call: `foo(bar)`

But when I try to define `foo` like this I get the error:

> error C2672: `foo`: no matching overloaded function found
>   error C2784: `void foo(void (__cdecl *)(ARGS...,T* ,int *),ARGS...)`: could not deduce template argument for `void (__cdecl* )(ARGS...,T *,int* )` from `void (bool,char *,int* )`

What can I do to help with the deduction?

Comment: Use `template <typename Func, typename... ARGS> void foo(Func func, ARGS... params);` instead?

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually wanted to specialize based on `T`... So I can't really just take the function pointer type as a template parameter.

Comment: Variadic argument packs used in deduction can only be used at the end of a signature -- so approaching the problem from this perspective will not work. You will likely need to deduce the entirety of the signature, and use SFINAE to constraint the allowable arguments, and dispatch functionality according to what the last two arguments are deduced to.

Comment: @Bitwize If you could show me how to build up to this such that I could specialize based on `T` It'd def be worth an accept and an upvote to me :)

Comment: @JonathanMee I am at work at the moment, but will try to find time on my lunch break. What version of C++ are you compiling against?

Comment: @Bitwize I'm using Visual Studio 2017... so a weird hybrid of C++14 and C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because `ARGS...` is a variadic pack, and when used for deduction it can only be used at the *end* of a function signature. For example, you could deduce:

```
void(*)(int,Args...)
```

But you cannot deduce

```
void(*)(Args...,int)
```

Since your problem requires the *last* argument to be a specific kind, and the second-last to be deduced specifically, you will need to deduce the entire function signature of `func`, and use SFINAE to prevent accidentally invoking this function with the wrong arguments.

To do that, we first need a way to extract out the `nth` last parameter. A simple type trait for this could be written as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

// A simple type-trait that gets the Nth type from a variadic pack
// If N is negative, it extracts from the opposite end of the pack
// (e.g. -1 == the last entry)
template<int N, bool IsPositive, typename...Args>
struct extract_nth_impl;

template<typename Arg0, typename...Args>
struct extract_nth_impl<0,true,Arg0,Args...> {
  using type = Arg0;
};

template<int N, typename Arg0, typename...Args>
struct extract_nth_impl<N,true,Arg0,Args...>
  : extract_nth_impl<N-1,true,Args...>{};

template<int N, typename...Args>
struct extract_nth_impl<N,false,Args...> {
  using type = typename extract_nth_impl<(sizeof...(Args)+N),true,Args...>::type;
};

// A type-trait wrapper to avoid the need for 'typename'
template<int N, typename...Args>
using extract_nth_t = typename extract_nth_impl<N,(N>=0),Args...>::type;
```

We can use this to extract the last parameter to ensure it's `int*`, and the second-last parameter to know it's type (`T*`). Then we can just use `std::enable_if` to SFINAE-away any bad-inputs, so that this function will fail to compile if misused.

```
template<
  typename...Args,
  typename...UArgs,
  typename=std::enable_if_t<
    (sizeof...(Args) >= 2) &&
    (sizeof...(Args)-2)==(sizeof...(UArgs)) &&
    std::is_same_v<extract_nth_t<-1,Args...>,int*> &&
    std::is_pointer_v<extract_nth_t<-2,Args...>>
  >
>
void foo(void(*func)(Args...), UArgs&&...params)
{
    // your code here, e.g.:
    // bar(func, std::forward<UArgs>(params)...);
}
```

**Note:** The template and the signature has changed in the following ways:

1. We now have `Args...` *and* `UArgs...`. This is because we want to capture N arguments types for `func`, but we only want `N-2` arguments for `params`
2. We now match `void(*func)(Args...)` instead of `void(*func)(Args...,T*,int*)`. `T*` is no longer a `template` parameter
3. We have this long `std::enable_if_t` which is used to SFINAE away bad cases, such as `N<2`, too many params for the number of signature args, `T*` (second-last argument) not being a pointer, and the last signature arg being `int*`

But overall this works. If `T` was needed in the definition of the function, you can extract it easily with:

```
    using T = std::remove_point_t<extract_nth_t<-2,Args...>>;
```

(Note: `remove_pointer_t` used to match only against the type, and not the pointer)

The following test cases work for me using `clang-8.0` and `-std=c++17`:

```
void example1(bool, char*, int*){}
void example2(bool, int*, int*){}
void example3(char*, int*){}
void example4(char*, char*){}

int main() {
  foo(&::example1,false);
  // foo(&::example1); -- fails to compile - too few arguments (correct)
  foo(&::example2,false);
  // foo(&::example2,false,5); -- fails to compile - too many arguments (correct)
  foo(&::example3);
  // foo(&::example4); -- fails to compile - last argument is not int* (correct)
}
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by @max66, this solution does not constrain convertible types as input to `param`. This does mean that it may fail if any `param` is not properly convertible. A separate condition to `std::enable_if` could be added to rectify this, if this is an important quality attribute of the API.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're looking something as follows

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ...Ts>
using revType = std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Ts)-1u-N, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

template <typename ... As1, typename ... As2,
          typename T = revType<1u, As1...>,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
             std::tuple<As1...>, std::tuple<As2..., T, int*>>, int> = 0>
void foo(void(*f)(As1...), As2 ... as)
 {
 }
```

As pointed by Bitwize (thanks) this solution has a great limits: require that the arguments of `foo()` (of types `As2...`) are deduced **exactly** as the corresponding types for `As1...`. So if `As1...` start with an `std::string`, you can't pass `"abc"` as first `As2...` parameter because `"abc"` is a `char const [4]` that is convertible but different to `std::string`.

As suggested by Bitwize itself, you can avoid this problem using `std::is_convertible`, instead `std::is_same_v`, over tuples taking advantage from `std::tuple` converting constructor, so

```
template <typename ... As1, typename ... As2,
          typename T = revType<1u, As1...>,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<
             std::tuple<As1...>, std::tuple<As2..., T, int*>>, int> = 0>
void foo(void(*f)(As1...), As2 ... as)
 {
 }
```

In this case, if you want to be sure that the last `As1...` type is **exactly** `int *` (and not only convertible), you can add the check

```
template <typename ... As1, typename ... As2,
          typename T = revType<1u, As1...>,
          typename U = revType<0u, As1...>,
          std::enable_if_t<
                std::is_convertible_v<std::tuple<As1...>,
                                      std::tuple<As2..., T, int*>>
             && std::is_same_v<int *, U>, int> = 0>
void foo(void(*f)(As1...), As2 ... as)
 {
 }
```

Comment: @JonathanMee - obviously you can add constraints over `T`

Comment: That's pretty sleek comparing against tuples -- though one thing to consider is that this constrains the types that `As2`'s variadic pack can be deduced to. If `As1` takes a `short` as an additional parameter, and `As2` deduces an `int` from a literal -- this will fail the SFINAE since the `tuple`'s are not the same

Comment: @Bitwize - yes: unfortunately this is a limit of this solution. With C++17 it's easy to go around this limits (`std::is_convertible` plus template folding... maybe I'll add an example) but in C++14 require  some heavy boilerplate (I suppose); maybe it's OK your solution (that doesn't check at all the correspondence for `UArgs...`) in case `f()` is called with `params` inside `foo()` (and I suppose it's a reasonable supposition).

Comment: @max66 I only omitted it in my solution because I wasn't using `std::tuple`, and didn't want to write a whole separate type trait to solve it. Using `std::tuple`, I think you could probably satisfy this with `std::is_constructible` instead of `std::is_same` since `std::tuple` has conversion constructors -- though this will require an explicit check that the last type is still `int*`.

Comment: @Bitwize - I didn't considered the `std::tuple` converting constructor; this solves the problem also in C++14; thanks. And, yes: in this case you have also to check that the last `As1...` is **exactly** `int *`. Considering this I've generalized the `getPenultimate` type traits. (About this... in your solution, isn't simpler to use `std::tuple_element_t` instead developing a recursive `extract_nth_impl`?)

Comment: @JonathanMee - answer improved with a great help from Bitwize.

Comment: @max66 It presents a quick/sleek solution, however IMO the effort is minor to write this trait. I'd rather write a simple trait than pull in all of `<tuple>` only to use it for variadic-pack handling and comparisons. Plus, the trait works with _any_ types, even `void`, whereas `std::tuple` does not. Though since the context of this is parameters, the benefit is moot.